# If we have density and mass why should we have gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, density, home-experiment

In a cup filled with different solutions with different densities if we put objects of different masses they will sink to different layers ... and this can be explained by mass and density so what is the role of gravity in this?

Comment: What would be different in your description if gravity wasn't there?

Comment: Why are the different masses sinking to different layers?

Comment: Gravity is attracting different masses to the earth as results you can see that different masses sink(move down closer to earth). You can draw a picture to see that when mass/participle stabilize in the solution gravity force $F=mg$ equals force of Archimedes $F_A=\rho V g$.

Comment: Also, the masses of the different objects you put into this system will not determine where they sink to. This will just depend on their densities.

Comment: One might ask, in the absence of gravity, how would one define the word "sink"?

Comment: @Steeven Nothing will change actually , if i said that gravity make them move downwards i can also say that mass only can do this i think ?

Comment: @SalmaTolba If gravity didn't exist, why would the mass move downwards in the first place?  What would "down" even be?  Objects with mass move down on Earth because there is gravity between the object and the Earth.  Gravity is the force that attracts two masses.  Masses alone would have no "downwards" to go towards.

Comment: @SalmaTolba Do you mean to say that even without gravity, if we were to place some object to even touch the top layer of fluid, it would then get sucked into the layers just because of the densities of the object and layers?

Comment: @Salma Imagine that you do the experiment inside a spaceship floating around far from any gravity. The object still has its mass. But will it still sink?

Answer (score 3):

The comments are basically all answers - the force that makes things float is the Buoyant force, and for an object of volume $V$ floating in a liquid of density $\rho$, the Buoyant force is
$$F_B=\rho g V.$$
So the gravitational constant appears right in the formula. In addition, the downwards force which is making the object sink is the gravitational force,
$$F_g=mg.$$
So this scenario of objects floating in liquids of different density would not occur in absence of the gravitational force.

EDIT: From your comment above, I suspect you might be wanting to think "what about if I did this away from any sources of gravity?" In that case you would have to consider the fluid pressure being applied to the object in each direction, and that would determine it's movement.  Of course, the fluid pressure would depend sensitively on the physical situation we are considering.

Comment: Then if we tried the experiment away from any source of gravity and put matters of different masses in fluids with different denisties they won't move downwards ?

Comment: @SalmaTolba If there was no gravity, what would be downwards?

Comment: @badjohn: You can define "downwards" independent of gravity, just a pick a coordinate system. Of course you're right in that you would have to pick, rather then such a preferred direction automatically given to you.

Comment: @SalmaTolba No they would not. Even if you decided what direction "down" was, the direction of their motion would be determined by the pressure of the fluid they were in. Specifically, they would move in the direction of the lowest pressure.

Comment: @levitopher I would hope that if someone picked an arbitrary definition of down then they would not expect stuff around them to care about it.  If I define down to be what is usually called up then I don't start to float.